# How to get route meta and all route meta on the component in Nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

My project package.json

```json
"dependencies": {     
  "core-js": "^3.15.1",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
  "nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.9.1",     
}
```

My pages directory

```
- pages
  - a.vue
  - b.vue
```

Page component

```js
// a.vue
<template>    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({   
  meta: {
    title: 'PageA'      
  },
})
export default class extends Vue {
  public mounted() {
    // ignored... see the below
  }
}
</script>
 
// b.vue
<template>    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({   
  meta: {
    title: 'PageB'      
  },
})
export default class extends Vue {}
</script>
```

In `a.vue` I want to get the route meta and all route meta.

- For the route meta.

```js
public mounted() {          
    console.log(this.$route.meta);
    console.log(this.$nuxt.$options.context.route.meta);
    console.log(this.$nuxt.context.route.meta);
     
    // {}
    // [{{title: "PageA"}}]
    // [{{title: "PageA"}}]
}
```

- For all routes meta.

```js
public mounted() {        
    console.log(this.$router.getRoutes().map((r) => r.meta));
    console.log(this.$router.options.routes?.map((r) => r.meta));
    console.log(this.$nuxt.$router.getRoutes().map(r => r.meta));
     
    // [{},{}]
    // [undefined, undefined]
    // [{},{}]
}
```

#### My question:

**About geting route meta**

- Why the `this.$route.meta` is empty ? I can use the $route.meta in the vue cli project to get route meta. Is this a bug in nuxtjs ?
- What's the difference between `this.$nuxt.$options.context.route.meta` and `this.$nuxt.context.route.meta` ?

**About geting all routes meta**

- What is correct way to get the all routes meta in nuxtjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Use [@nuxtjs/router-extras](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) to set the router meta and everything work fine.

Page component

```
// a.vue
<template></template>
<router lang="js">
  {
    meta: {
      title: 'PageA'
    }
  }
</router>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue {
  public mounted() {
    // ignored... see the below
  }
}
</script>

// b.vue
<template></template>
<router lang="js">
  {
    meta: {
      title: 'PageB'
    }
  }
</router>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue {}
</script>
```

In `a.vue` get the current route meta and all route meta.

```
  public mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.meta)
    console.log(this.$nuxt.$options.context.route.meta)
    console.log(this.$nuxt.context.route.meta)  
    // {title: "PageA"}
    // [{{title: "PageA"}}]
    // [{{title: "PageA"}}]
    
    console.log(this.$router.getRoutes().map((r) => r.meta))
    console.log(this.$router.options.routes?.map((r) => r.meta))
    console.log(this.$nuxt.$router.getRoutes().map((r) => r.meta))  
    // [{title: "PageA"},{title: "PageB"}]
    // [{title: "PageA"},{title: "PageB"}]
    // [{title: "PageA"},{title: "PageB"}]
  }
```